# Header in section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to copy the header in section, shown in this picture: [image: SectionHeader]

I' trying to add a label and the separator line inside the same view.
So far I have this code that isn't working at all...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, 50-1, 320, 1);
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sectionHeader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(66/255.0) green:(139/255.0) blue:(18/255.0) alpha:1] ;
    //sectionHeader.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section];

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            sectionHeader.text =NSLocalizedString(@"ACTIVO", nil) ;
            [customView addSubview:sectionHeader];
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionHeader.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PASSIVO",nil);
            [customView addSubview:sectionHeader];
            break;
    }

    return customView;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated since I'm new to IOS, thanks in Advance.

Comment: provide some frame to your `UILabel` object

Comment: Please explain in a more detailed way please :)

Comment: Your `sectionHeader` not has any frame. set some frame value for `sectionHeader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code should accomplish what you want (including the line on the bottom):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:customView.frame];
    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sectionHeader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(66/255.0) green:(139/255.0) blue:(18/255.0) alpha:1];
    sectionHeader.text = NSLocalizedString(section == 0 ? @"ACTIVO" : @"PASSIVO", nil);
    [customView addSubview:sectionHeader];

    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, customView.frame.size.height - 1, customView.frame.size.width, 1)];    
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(66/255.0) green:(139/255.0) blue:(18/255.0) alpha:1];    
    [customView addSubview:lineView];    

    return customView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, 50-1, 320, 44); //FIX THIS
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame]; //FIX THIS
    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sectionHeader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(66/255.0) green:(139/255.0) blue:(18/255.0) alpha:1] ;
    //sectionHeader.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section];


    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            sectionHeader.text =NSLocalizedString(@"ACTIVO", nil) ;
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionHeader.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PASSIVO",nil);
            break;                
    }
    [customView addSubview:sectionHeader];

    return customView;
}
```

You need to give proper frames to your UI Element. Look for "//FIX THIS" in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, 50-1, 320, 50); // change here your view's height
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame];
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame]; // also change here in label frame
sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
sectionHeader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(66/255.0) green:(139/255.0) blue:(18/255.0) alpha:1] ;
//sectionHeader.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section];

switch (section) {
    case 0:
        sectionHeader.text =NSLocalizedString(@"ACTIVO", nil) ;
        [customView addSubview:sectionHeader];
        break;
    case 1:
        sectionHeader.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PASSIVO",nil);
        [customView addSubview:sectionHeader];
        break;
}

return customView;

}
```

// and also write this method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I just wanna copy the design nothing else :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

It states that you must also implement:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

for it to work properly.